# NoMethodError in Welcome#index - Getting Started with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, crud

[Screenshot Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTblc.png)

Need help for this error. I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. I did research for related topics online but I can't find any solution. Below are the codes.

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->

<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'articles' %>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Here's the code from the controller.

```
# welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Config codes

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `@articles` is nil. Show us your `welcome_controller`

Comment: I'll update the code update the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Undefined method each for nil:NilClass

The error is due to `@articles` is `nil`. You should define it in the `welcome#index`

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end 
end
```

However you can tweak the `index.html.erb` to avoid such errors

```
<% unless @articles.blank? %>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Complementing: it is usefull to check if article is nil at index.html.erb before iterating through it

Comment: You're so awesome @Pavan. All is now working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Pavan's answer is correct and will solve your issue! As you getting started, I decided to write this answer to explain a little more what was happening:

You're routing root to 'welcome#index', i.e., when you hit http://localhost:300/ it you call method `index` from `WelcomeController`. We are used to call it index action from WelcomeController.

After run this method, it will (by default) render the file `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`. See the pattern? The action name is the same as the file name and the controller name is the same as the folder name containing this file.

In this file you were using `@articles`. This is a variable that was defined in `WelcomeController#index`.

**Your issue:** this variable wasn't defined in the controller, resulting a nil object. I.e, it doesn't existed.

**Solution:** define this variable as @Pavan suggested.

But you could fall into the same exception again: if you haven't articles saved. To prevent this case you just need to check if @articles is nil, as @Pavan suggested too.

Hope this answer will clarify the issue and the suggestions to solve it!